# Trying to output a string variable to a .txt file within an IF statement. - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, output

I'm pretty new to java and i still have alot to learn. I'm trying to output the data within a variable to a text file, and I'm not sure why this will not work. Could anyone help me out?

```
if ("Y".equals(output_to_file)) {
        System.out.print("You selected Yes");
        PrintStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"));
            out.print(first_input);
        }
        finally {
            if (out != null) out.close();
        }
    }
    else System.out.print("You selected No");
```

"(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"))" is underlined red, and it says: Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you're doing file operations, there is the possiblity that a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown. Therefore, Java wants you to tell it what to do in the event that one is thrown. Thus, you need to add a `catch` clause for the possible `FileNotFoundException`. You already have a try block, so you simply need to add a `catch` clause before your `finally` clause:

```
        try {
        out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"));
        out.print(first_input);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        //do something in the event that a FNFE is thrown
        }
        finally {
        if (out != null) out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Since you're new here, a heads up - if my answer (or anyone else's) helped you, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. Doing so will give you +2 reputation points, and increase the likelihood that folks will help you out in the future :)

Comment: Thanks, going to checkmark in it two minutes when it will allow me to. :D